# Gobuffalo error "There is no connection named development defined!"

Tags: go, data-migration

In my go project I install gobuffalo:

```
go get github.com/gobuffalo/pop/...
```

And then I run `soda migrate` but I got this error `There is no connection named development defined!`

Does anyone know what problem I am facing with?

Comment: it seems like a configuration issue, you should probably check your database.yml file

Comment: It works on my local computer and when I try to deploy it to the server It didn't work. Still trying to figure it out

Answer (score 2):

First a quick reply, explanation below.

1. Delete the database.yml file.
2. Force soda to create the same file with the command "soda g config"
3. After that my "soda migrate" command stopped giving the error and worked. (Don't forget to put your db cofig details in the generated file in the first section (development) only)

***In Detail***

Actually I copied an old working directory of Go to create another one. In the new place it was not working. I think that was the problem. If still not working try installing SODA and do the above in the new place, I did that also.
https://gobuffalo.io/documentation/database/soda/
https://gobuffalo.io/documentation/database/configuration/

Answer (score 0):

For me, I named the file database.yaml initially, changing the name of file to  database.yml worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you don't have any formatting extension's available I was initially getting the same issue later resolved by 'uninstalling' prettier.

Steps I followed:

- 'soda g config' and edit your database.yml (make sure it is 'database.yml')
- I was also creating some Fizz migrations 'soda generate fizz table_name'
- Edit changes to the database.yml file (I am using Dbeaver by default it usually asks you to set user as 'postgres' and if you have any password set in order to make connection with 'postgres' you can use that same password in the password)
- i.e
  development:
  dialect: postgres
  database: db_name
  user: postgres
  password: ****
  host: 127.0.0.1
  pool: 5

  - now you can use 'soda migrate' or 'soda migrate up' in case you have some
    code there for creating a table
    may this approach helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Check what people mention above about 'database.yml' and not 'database.yaml'.

But for me what was causing issues was the last lines of that configuration. I've removed all 'test' and 'production' config keys.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm and make sure the database.yml file is well structured

WRONG

```
development:
  dialect: postgres
  database: db_name
  user: user_name
  password:my_password
  host: 127.0.0.1
  pool: 5
```

RIGHT

```
development:
  dialect: postgres
  database: db_name
  user: user_name
  password: my_password
  host: 127.0.0.1
  pool: 5
```

Notice the space between the password key and my_password value in the right structure

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I am using VS code. Uninstalling prettier helped me to run the migrations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35461494)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).